# Unity3D auto rotate screen to portrait or landscape mode for a specific scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my app to auto rotate the screen on different scene's, I've made a script but it didn't work, what do I need to change?

This is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Start in landscape mode
    void Start() 
    {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to

File -> Build Settings -> PlayerSettings -> Under Resolution and Presentation -> Default Orientation -> [Change to LandScapeLeft]

if you can't find it make sure your target platform is IOS Android or UWP (Mobile devices)

if you're sure your script is Executing add these two lines

```
  Screen.autorotateToPortrait = false;
   Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown =false ;
```

Comment: Yeah but on starter screen I want to be just portrait

Comment: I’m not sure why your script doesn’t work not enough information was provided, what platform are you testing it on ? , I would also suggest making sure it runs by doing something like 'Debug.Log("Screen Orientation Script Executing");'

Comment: It runs on Android!